# ¿Cómo agrego un icono de Fontastic a la derecha del texto de un boton?

Tags: css, fuentes, icons

Estoy usando Fontastic para traerme unos iconos y se los quiero agregar a un texto que esta dentro de un boton. Los iconos me aparecen a izquierda, pero yo quiero que aparezcan después.

Así tengo el código:

```
button.button.icon-caret-down Filtrar
button.button.icon-caret-down Ordenar
```

Encontes se ve así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que se arregla usando :before y :after pero no encuentro la forma

Otra forma de escribir ese codigo es así:

```
button.button(data-icon="k") Filtrar
button.button(data-icon="k") Ordenar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te recomiendo que los iconos los agregues no en el div que contiene tu texto, sino más bien que crees un span dentro de ese div y a ese span sí le pones tu clase de icono, por ejemplo:

```css
.button{
background: grey;
color: #333;
padding: 10px;
display: table;
}
.button i{
font-style: normal;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.button span{
vertical-align: middle;
margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <i>Filtrar</i>
  <span class="icon-caret-down">e</span>
</div>
```

Donde yo puse la "e" dentro del span en realidad no debes poner nada, ahí se te generará un "before" y obviamente, colores, etc, haces lo que quieras :D

Comment: Había hecho lo mismo antes y ahora lo volví a hacer. El icono queda se mueve un poco verticalmente y deja de estar centrado. No sé si serán propiedades del navegador. Pero pensé que podía escribirlo con pseudoclases

Comment: Aveces pasa que los iconos la imagen en sí tiene márgenes por lo que es difícil que te quede centrado, no obstante al span que tiene la imagen puedes darle esto: position: relative; top: -5px; (juega con este top hasta que te quede centrado).